# How to delete a page to show 404 server error through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, internal-server-error, server-error

I am unable to remove a page of a component of Joomla site, due to dynamic nature of it as created.
How is it possible that i can display 404 server error, if that exact url is opened or linked by by any one

The page is

```
  www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_forum&view=ask
```

May be through htaccess, if there is any possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code in your main .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_forum&view=ask$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. But its redirecting the page to 404. However, i was wishing if the server response itself is 404 without redirecting the page to 404 on crawling the page.

Comment: Didn't get it. Do you want to show a custom 404 page when 404 occurs?

Comment: No. I mean, the page should show Server Error when opened as if was never there. However, the code you provided, though showing server error but itd done as redirect to 404 error page. Is it possible to directly show server error without having a redirect

Comment: My code is is not doing any redirect to 404 page since I have `-` in target URL. Most likely you have some other directive like `ErrorDocument 404` which is causing this.

Comment: Just this code will show default Apache 404 message: `The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I have checked this code on another site and to tell you as been said - it works well with 404 error code. I guess may be some other directive is impacting on the main site. Will check this out. Thanks once again for solution !